# Userform to search on two column from data range

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment, I am searching on one column. But I am stuck on how to search on two or multiple fields to bring up more of a specific result.

I am trying to narrow my search down from 1 to 2 to bring up more specific data. Can anyone help. Thanks in Advance. Appreciate the help!!!!!

```
Public CallDetails As Collection

Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String) As Collection

Dim rng_to_search As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim FoundItem As clsCallDetails

Set CallDetails = New Collection

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set rng_to_search = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

With rng_to_search
    'Look for the first instance.
    Set rFound = .Find(what:=NumberToFind, _
                       after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = rFound.Address
        Do
            Set FoundItem = New clsCallDetails 'Create a new instance of the class to hold the details.
            With FoundItem
                .Title = rFound.Offset(, 7) 'CORRECT
                .LoggedBy = rFound.Offset(, 2) 'CORRECT .Offset from column A by 1 column, so column B.
                .CallNumber = rFound.Offset(, 3) 'CORRECT
                .DateField = rFound.Offset(, 4) 'CORRECT
                .OwnerField = rFound.Offset(, 6) 'CORRECT
                .Description = rFound.Offset(, 8) 'CORRECT
                .Solution = rFound.Offset(, 9) 'CORRECT
                .URLImage = rFound.Offset(, 10) 'CORRECT
                .DateResolved = rFound.Offset(, 5) 'CORRECT
                .Reference = rFound.Offset(, 1) 'CORRECT

            End With
            CallDetails.Add FoundItem 'Add the class instance to our collection.
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound) 'Look for the next value.

        'Continue searching until we reach the top again.
        Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Function
```

---

```
Private Sub PlaceValues(Index As Long)
With Me
    .txtLoggedBy.Value = CallDetails(Index).LoggedBy
    .txtCallNumber.Value = CallDetails(Index).CallNumber
    .txtDateField.Value = CallDetails(Index).DateField
    .txtTitle.Value = CallDetails(Index).Title
    .cmbOwnerField.Value = CallDetails(Index).OwnerField
    .txtDescription.Value = CallDetails(Index).Description
    .txtSolution.Value = CallDetails(Index).Solution
    .txtURLImage.Value = CallDetails(Index).URLImage
    .txtDateResolved.Value = CallDetails(Index).DateResolved
    .txtReference.Value = CallDetails(Index).reference
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When you find the result in one column you could check an offset to see if matches the second value, or perhaps use Autofilter.

Comment: Could you perhaps show me an example. I'm very new to VB.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a very basic idea of doing this. The function allows each variable to be passed to the function. These are optional so they don't have to be provided. It then tests the ones which are provided against the values that have been found and if they match gives them increases the `Score` by 1. If the final score then exceeds or is equal to a `Tolerance` it adds it to your custom collection. You'll have to modify this slightly for the correct data types and comparitive methods.

```
Public CallDetails As Collection

Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String, Optional Title As String, Optional LoggedBy As String, _
    Optional CallNumber As Long, Optional DateField As Long, Optional OwnerField As String, Optional Description As String, _
    Optional Solution As String, Optional URLImage As String, Optional DateResolved As Long, Optional reference As String) As Collection

    Dim rng_to_search As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim FoundItem As clsCallDetails
    Dim Score As Long
    Dim Tolerance As Long

    Set CallDetails = New Collection

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
        Set rng_to_search = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Tolerance = 8

    With rng_to_search
        'Look for the first instance.
        Set rFound = .Find(what:=NumberToFind, _
                           after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                With rFound
                    If Title = rFound.Offset(, 7) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If LoggedBy = rFound.Offset(, 2) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If CallNumber = rFound.Offset(, 3) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If DateField = rFound.Offset(, 4) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If OwnerField = rFound.Offset(, 6) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If Description = rFound.Offset(, 8) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If Solution = rFound.Offset(, 9) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If URLImage = rFound.Offset(, 10) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If DateResolved = rFound.Offset(, 5) Then Score = Score + 1
                    If reference = rFound.Offset(, 1) Then Score = Score + 1
                End With

                If Score >= Tolerance Then
                    Set FoundItem = New clsCallDetails 'Create a new instance of the class to hold the details.
                    With FoundItem
                        .Title = rFound.Offset(, 7) 'CORRECT
                        .LoggedBy = rFound.Offset(, 2) 'CORRECT .Offset from column A by 1 column, so column B.
                        .CallNumber = rFound.Offset(, 3) 'CORRECT
                        .DateField = rFound.Offset(, 4) 'CORRECT
                        .OwnerField = rFound.Offset(, 6) 'CORRECT
                        .Description = rFound.Offset(, 8) 'CORRECT
                        .Solution = rFound.Offset(, 9) 'CORRECT
                        .URLImage = rFound.Offset(, 10) 'CORRECT
                        .DateResolved = rFound.Offset(, 5) 'CORRECT
                        .reference = rFound.Offset(, 1) 'CORRECT
                    End With
                    CallDetails.Add FoundItem 'Add the class instance to our collection.
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound) 'Look for the next value.
                End If
                Score = 0

            'Continue searching until we reach the top again.
            Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

For your class to hold a `Score` value as well you should just need to add

```
Private pScore As Long
Public Property Get Score() As Long
    Score = pScore
End Property
Public Property Let Score(value As Long)
    pScore = value
End Property
```

to `clsCallDetails`

Comment: I have changed     Dim Tolerance As Long to     Dim Tolerance As String and now I get an error on    Tolerance = 8 it says object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: `Tolerance` and `Score` are both numerical values so need to be declared as `Long` or `Integer`

Comment: If you wanted to you could edit your custom class to take a `Score` value also or whatever you want to call it and then sort by the `Score` so that your results are ordered by relevance

Comment: Not entirely sure on how to edit the custom class. But, I am getting an error and I have provided the code in the original question. I am getting an error Invalid procedure call or argument on line where it says .txtLoggedBy.Value = CallDetails(Index).LoggedBy

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to add the `Score` to your class for the other bit are you sure `Index` is getting set?

Comment: I have set the index to long for PlaceValues. But I am still getting this error (Invalid procedure call or argument)

Comment: Your code looks okay, but issue seems to be within Private Sub PlaceValues(Index As Long). The code is above for it

Comment: What is the value that `Index` is holding? step through your code and when it gets to that line hold your mouse over `Index` to see if it holds a value. failing that add `Debug.Print Index` to the beginning of your `PlaceValues` Sub to see what it is trying to use in the Immediate window

Comment: There's no reason for it not to work unless `Index` is incorrect or the collection isn't getting populated

Comment: I have hovered over it and it brings up index = 1

Comment: I have added the Debug.Print Index, but it brings up error message stating compile error

Comment: Yes on that line where I've put Debug.Print before Private Sub. It brings up Compile error expected: expression

Comment: It needs to go **after** the `Private Sub` line